# How to add custom field into MarketPress (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

How to add custom field into MarketPress (Wordpress)?

I want to add 2 custom fields, one text field more and one number field more.

How can I do that?

MarketPress: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/e-commerce/

Comment: it's a paid plugin you should get support there. Also I do suppose the have documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I installed plugin "Advanced Custom Fields" and that's it. :)